# Trying to run Java class from c++ using JNI, segmentation fault :/

Tags: java, c++, linux, oracle, jvm

Below is the code I'm using and the compile command. I'm somewhat new to c++ and don't really know how to go about debugging a segmentation fault, doesn't really give much info. Any advice would be much appreciated!

```
#include <jni.h>       /* where everything is defined */

int main() {
    JNIEnv *env1;
    JavaVM**  jvm1;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args1;
    JavaVMOption options1[3];
    options1[0].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/";
    options1[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
    options1[2].optionString = "-Dulimit -c unlimited";
    options1[0].extraInfo = NULL;
    options1[1].extraInfo = NULL;
    options1[2].extraInfo = NULL;
    vm_args1.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args1.nOptions = 3;
    vm_args1.options = options1;
    vm_args1.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;


    int reAt = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm1, (void**)&env1, &vm_args1);


    return 0;
}
```

**As far as I can tell the line causing the problem is the JNI_CreateJavaVM line, when commented out there is no segmentation fault**

To compile have tried both of these:

g++ -g main.cpp -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include/linux -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm

g++ -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include/linux/ -L /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server main.cpp -l jvm -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server -o a2.out

Comment: First of all: Find out on which line the segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: Maybe the 3rd option needs to address option1[2] instead of option1[1] ?

Comment: And `vm_args1.nOptions` should be set to 3 and not 1 since you have 3 options.

Comment: OK, changed the 3rd option, and set nOptions to 3. Tried with both compile commands but still get segmentation fault :(

Comment: I commented out the JNI_CreateJavaVM line, and it then doesn't give a segmentation fault, so I'm guessing that's the problematic line.